# Showing the arrow selection indicator between fragments as seen in android docs

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the visual examples seen here:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html#combining-views

How does one show the arrow pointing from the detail fragment to the selected record in the master fragment seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I would surmise that there are two background drawables for the list. One with the dropshadow + edge and the blue one with the indentation.

Comment: yeah... I just wanted to make sure there wasn't something built in before I proceeded down that path. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shadow Separator Between Android Fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670905/shadow-separator-between-android-fragments)